# Menu icons not working for MFC ribbon app

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, ribbon

As the title says, if I have a popup menu in my MFC ribbon application, it does not display menu icons beside each menu option.  The same code, same resources does display icons in tool bar based application.  The code I'm using to display my context / popup menu is as follows;

```
CMenu menu;
    VERIFY(menu.LoadMenu(m_MenuID));
    CMenu* pPopup = menu.GetSubMenu(0);
    ASSERT(pPopup != NULL);
    CWnd* pWndPopupOwner = CWnd::GetFocus();
    while (pWndPopupOwner->GetStyle() & WS_CHILD)
        pWndPopupOwner = pWndPopupOwner->GetParent();
    pPopup->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, m_MenuPoint.x, m_MenuPoint.y,
        pWndPopupOwner);
    for (int i=0; i<pPopup->GetMenuItemCount(); i++)
        pPopup->EnableMenuItem(0,MF_BYPOSITION | MF_ENABLED);
```

Any way around this?

**Edit:**  Extract of resources used as requested;

```
IDR_ACTION_ADDPTS MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "_POPUP_"
    BEGIN
       MENUITEM "Arc 2Pts+Radius",             ID_CIRCARC_ARC_2PT_RAD
       MENUITEM "Arc 2Pts+Tangent",            ID_CIRCARC_ARC_2PT_TAN
       MENUITEM "Arc 3Pts",                    ID_CIRCARC_ARC_3PT
    END
END

IDR_ARCS TOOLBAR 16, 15
BEGIN
    BUTTON      ID_CIRCARC_ARC_2PT_RAD
    BUTTON      ID_CIRCARC_ARC_2PT_TAN
    BUTTON      ID_CIRCARC_ARC_3PT
END

STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    ID_CIRCARC_ARC_2PT_RAD  "Create an arc with two points and a radius\nArc 2Pts+Radius"
    ID_CIRCARC_ARC_2PT_TAN  "Create an arc with two points and an incoming tangent\nArc 2Pts+Tangent"
    ID_CIRCARC_ARC_3PT      "Create an arc with three points\nArc 3Pts"
END
```

Comment: The resource definition statements should be part of the question.

Comment: The application I'm developing now is toolbar-based and displays a pop-up menu with icons. The wizard-generated code calls `theApp.GetContextMenuManager()->ShowPopupMenu(IDR_POPUP_EDIT, point.x, point.y, this, TRUE);` to display the pop-up menu. Maybe try this, or else... dig into the MFC source to see what's going on (maybe some custom code or even a custom class). As a sidenote, why enable menu items AFTER the menu is displayed? And that for loop only enables item 0, not i. Btw MFC applications should best use the OnUpadateUI() handlers to enable/disable menu commands.